# Adobe Flash/ Animate muting particular audio

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, actionscript

I am in *desperate* need of help! I have a mute toggle button that I made following a tutorial on youtube in Adobe Animate/Flash using action-script 3.0 and it mutes everything as it is supposed to. However, I now need it to only mute the background music as it is muting my videos as well! How can I alter the code to either make sure only the background sound is muted and not the video?

```html
function setMute(vol)
{
 var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(1,0);
 sTransform.volume = vol; 
 SoundMixer.soundTransform = sTransform;
}


var Mute:Boolean = false;

mute_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,toggleMute_btn);

function toggleMute_btn(event:Event){ if(Mute)
{
 Mute = false; setMute(1);
soundLines.gotoAndStop(1);
}
else
 { Mute = true; setMute(0);
soundLines.gotoAndStop(2); 
 }
}
```

Comment: I think you may need a different transform for each sound that you want to control separately.

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe Animate (AS3), a developer can add audio in mainly two ways, timeline audio and external audio loaded by script. There can be even more methods of adding sound to a Flash movie.

In case of timeline audio, which are embedded and plays on movie progress, you may simply stop that movieclip containing that audio causing mute-like effect for that specific audio.

Example:

If your movieclip named BG contains your background music, you can write `BG.stop();` for mute and `BG.play();` for resuming the audio. This is the easiest method of all.

In case of streaming audio from external source using code,

```
var bg:Sound = new Sound();
var bgChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
bg.load(new URLRequest("test.mp3"));
bgChannel = bg.play();
function vol(v:uint){
    var sT:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
    sT.volume = v;
    bgChannel.soundTransform=sT;
}
setTimeout(vol,1000,0);
```

Similarly, set vol to higher value for unmute.